# Keep text, dynamically updated, centered within a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have the following canvas:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:0px;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

javascript:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(200, 200, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

I want to write a score within the center of the canvas:

```
var score = 0;score++;
ctx.fillText(score,200,200);
```

However this score will be updated and the more digit this value will be the less centered it will be.

I attempted to use the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript), but the "text" here, is merely a javascript variable named score and thus not considered a text.

Here is a fiddle where I played around to try to solve my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/27xfvLhh/

I see two potential way to obtain the result wanted:

1. Is there a way to fill the text directly centered within my canvas?
2. Is there a way to calculate what will be the size of the text?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to fill the text directly centered within my canvas?

You can use the properties `textAlign` for horizontal alignment and `textBaseline` for vertical alignment. Then calculate center point by for example using half the size of the canvas:

> Is there a way to calculate what will be the size of the text?

The `ctx.measureText("Text").width` will give you the width of the text in pixels using the current set font.

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "32px sans-serif";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillText("Some Centered Text", ctx.canvas.width>>1, ctx.canvas.height>>1);

// measure text
var width = ctx.measureText("Some Centered Text").width;
ctx.font = "20px sans-serif";
ctx.fillText(width + "px", ctx.canvas.width>>1, 90 + ctx.canvas.height>>1);
```

```css
#c {border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=600 height=300></canvas>
```